# Python turn image obj to binary file by using Image.fromqimage()

Tags: python, image, qr-code

I'm trying to deploy a python web server. Main function of following code is to generate a qrcode and transfer the image to binary file.

```
def generate_qrcode(date, user_id):
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(
        version=1,
        error_correction=constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
        box_size=10,
        border=4,
    )
    base_string = config_default.configs.get('const').get('url') + '/check_in/'
    generate_string = date + '#' +user_id
    qr.add_data(base_string + generate_string, qrcode)
    qr.make(fit=True)
    img = qr.make_image()
    return Image.fromqimage(img)  # here is the place returns exception
```

Then post this binary file to a url.

```
def upload_qrcode(datetime, user_id):
    url = "https://api.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/media/upload
    access_token = get_access_token()
    querystring = {"access_token":access_token,"type":"image"}
    files = {"media":generate_qrcode(datetime,user_id)}
    response = requests.post(url, params=querystring, files=files)
```

Here is the exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/yudayan/Documents/myCode/pythonCode/nuobao/QRC_maker.py", line 58, in <module>
main()
File "/Users/yudayan/Documents/myCode/pythonCode/nuobao/QRC_maker.py", line 54, in main
print(upload_qrcode("sdf", "adsf"))
File "/Users/yudayan/Documents/myCode/pythonCode/nuobao/QRC_maker.py", line 47, in upload_qrcode
files = {"media":generate_qrcode(datetime,user_id)}
File "/Users/yudayan/Documents/myCode/pythonCode/nuobao/QRC_maker.py", line 32, in generate_qrcode
return Image.fromqimage(img)
File "/Users/yudayan/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2321, in fromqimage
return ImageQt.fromqimage(im)
File "/Users/yudayan/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageQt.py", line 59, in fromqimage
if im.hasAlphaChannel():
File "/Users/yudayan/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qrcode/image/pil.py", line 50, in __getattr__
return getattr(self._img, name)
AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'hasAlphaChannel'
```

Comment: from PIL import image 
import qrcode

Comment: Just to hack past the current error, you could try: `img.hasAlphaChannel = lambda: False` before the `return Image.fromqimage(img)` line, to see if you can keep going. Odds are you are not using the Image class properly and need to define whether or not it actually has an alpha channel either in the artwork itself or in the program. Try to narrow down the cause by using different images, etc.

Comment: @JacobIRR Thank you for your answer, but still facing issue.
AttributeError: 'PpmImageFile' object has no attribute 'read'